# Prove that $|f_n(x)| ≤ M(x)$ given a point-wise converging function $f_n(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $$f_n(x)= \left\{\begin{array}{cc}
   n~;~&\mbox{for}~ 1/n^2 \leq x \leq 4/n^2,\\
   0~;~&\mbox{for}~ 0\leq x < 1/n^2~\text{or}~ 4/n^2< x \leq 1.
   \end{array}\right. $$
Prove that $|f_n(x)| ≤ M(x)$ for some function $M(x)\neq 0$.

My working:  If $x\in [0,1)$, then $f_n(x)= 0$ for all $x\leq 1/n^2$. Therefore, $f_n(x)= 0$ for as $n\to \infty$.  Also if $x=1$, then $f_n(x)=0$ for all $x\geq 1/n^2$.   Thus $f_n(x)\to 0$ point-wise as $n\to \infty$.

Is this working correct?  How do I proceed to compute the function $M(x)$?

Comment: $1/n^2 \leq x \leq 4/n^2$ means $1/\sqrt x \le n \le 2/\sqrt x$ Can you continue?

Comment: Thank you.  I can now proceed